# Restore Default settings Apple TV, how do I pair a new remote?

Tags: ios, appletv

I lost my remote for my Apple TV, and we were using the Remote App, but we recently downloaded a new update for the Apple TV and the update kept us from watching Movies.  I did a restore on the Apple TV, but now the Remote App cannot find my Apple TV.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the iPhone and Apple TV are connected to the same network?

Comment: Just to clarify – do you currently have a remote you can use to manouvre the Apple TV, or was the iOS app your only option until it failed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you deleted the original pairing from your Remote app to the Apple TV? I know I have had issues with my iTunes library not connecting after a OS reinstall even though I was connected to the same library, deleting the pairing and then reconnecting fixed my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This will be great if the OP really needs the infrared remote fixed/paired, but might need some more steps / another article on getting the iOS remote app paired with the device.